# How to make Multiple Checkbox in flutter dynamically and get their values together

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox, dynamically-generated

I am new in flutter I am facing a problem in creating a CheckBox with multiple items then the user can also select multiple items from the checkbox list. please help me, guys.

Comment: Could you better explain what you want to do? What is your use case?

Comment: I want to create a checkbox listview with multiple items & when user starts selecting them they will start adding into a new array then i have to show all the selected items into Text widget with updated items.

Comment: sorry for late response but i got simple solution without any packages, look once this might be help in future - 
1. Select only one from list - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71662868/9372923
2. Select multiple from list - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71672197/9372923

Answer (score 13):

you can try this widget *CheckboxListTile* :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DemoCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  DemoCheckState createState() => new DemoCheckState();
}

class DemoCheckState extends State<Demo> {
  Map<String, bool> values = {
    'foo': true,
    'bar': false,
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: Text('Demo')),
      body: ListView(
        children: values.keys.map((String key) {
          return new CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text(key),
            value: values[key],
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                values[key] = value;
              });
            },
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp( MaterialApp(home: DemoCheck()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, I need one more thing when i select any item form checkbox it will automatically adds all selected items into new array or map then i have to show selected items on screen using text widget. I will be very happy if you help me on this.

Comment: Please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64108301/handle-the-list-of-dynamic-checkboxes-when-the-widget-is-added-on-button-click-i