# Selecting only one checkbox list title in flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm building a selectable checkbox contact list in flutter but when I click on the single contact card, it selects all contacts, rather than just the one I clicked on. Please can someone guide me with an explanation of what I should change to allow only one contact tile to be selected at a time?

I'm not sure where to start. I thought maybe that when it was updating the (default false) _isSelected variable and then setting the state, it was setting the new (true) _isSelected variable to all the contacts. However, I am just starting out with flutter so I can't think how to implement a solution to this.

Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// TODO: make it ask for permissions otherwise the app crashes
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
List<Contact> contacts = [];
List<Contact> contactsFiltered = [];
TextEditingController searchController = new TextEditingController();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllContacts();
    searchController.addListener(() => filterContacts());
  }

String flattenPhoneNumber(String phoneStr){
  return phoneStr.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'^(\+)|\D'), (Match m) {
    return m[0] == "+" ? "+" : ""; 
  });
}

filterContacts() {
  List<Contact> _contacts = [];
  _contacts.addAll(contacts);
if (searchController.text.isNotEmpty) {
_contacts.retainWhere((contact) {
String searchTerm = searchController.text.toLowerCase();
String searchTermFlatten = flattenPhoneNumber(searchTerm);
String contactName = contact.displayName.toLowerCase();
bool nameMatches = contactName.contains(searchTerm);

var phone = contact.phones.firstWhere((phn) {
  String phnFlattened = flattenPhoneNumber(phn.value);
return phnFlattened.contains(searchTerm);
}, orElse: () => null);

if (searchTermFlatten.isEmpty) {
  return false;
}

if (nameMatches == true) {
  return true;
}

return phone != null;
});

setState((){
  contactsFiltered = _contacts;
});

}
}

 bool _isSelected = false;

  getAllContacts() async{
  Iterable<Contact> _contacts = (await ContactsService.getContacts()).toList();  
setState(() {
  contacts = _contacts;
});
}

int _currentIndex = 0;

final tabs = [
  Center(child: Text('Create New')),
  Center(child: Text('Click to confirm group creation')),
];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    bool isSearching = searchController.text.isNotEmpty;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[

            AppBar(
              title: Text('Create Group'),
            ),

            Container(
              child: TextField(
                controller: searchController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search Contacts',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                    )
                  ),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                  )
                ),
              ),
            ),

                 Expanded( child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: isSearching == true ? contactsFiltered.length : contacts.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    Contact contact = isSearching == true ? contactsFiltered[index] : contacts[index];
                    //TODO: make it so when you clear your search, all items appear again
                    return CheckboxListTile(
                      title: Text(contact.displayName),
                      subtitle: Text(contact.phones.elementAt(0).value),                      
                      value: _isSelected,
                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                          setState(() {
                          _isSelected = value;
                               // TODO: add in function to add contact ID to a list
                               //TODO: make it so that you can select a single one not just all
                          });
                          },

                          )
                        ;
                       },
                    ),
                     ),
                    new Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                     child: BottomNavigationBar(  
                currentIndex: _currentIndex,   

        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[


          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            title: Text('Add Contact'),
          ),

          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.create),
            title: Text('Create Group'),
          ),

        ],  
        onTap: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                  _currentIndex = index;
                  });     
                  }
        )
                    )
        )
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you have N contacts but only one `isSelected` variable, thats why you cannot represent N selected states using one bool variable

Comment: sorry for late response but i got simple solution without any packages, look once this might be help in future - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71662868/9372923

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `list` (more than one) of contacts and `single` variable `_isSelected` which controls all  of `CheckboxListTile`'s selected state

If your use case is to select any number of Contacts - you need to keep selected state of each single Contact

There more than one way, try next one

1. Track all selected contacts
2. Check if contact is selected and set result to `value:`
3. add or remove Contact from selected in `onChanged:` callback

`final selectedContacts = Set<Contact>();`

```
                ...
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                Contact contact = isSearching == true ? contactsFiltered[index] : contacts[index];
                //TODO: make it so when you clear your search, all items appear again
                return CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text(contact.displayName),
                  subtitle: Text(contact.phones.elementAt(0).value),                      
                  value: selectedContacts.contains(contact),
                  onChanged: (bool value) { 
                    if (value) { 
                      selectedContacts.add(contact); 
                    } else {
                      selectedContacts.remove(contact); 
                    }
                    setState((){}); 
                  }
                  ...
```

Comment: great thanks, the only issue I get now is on ` if (value) { 
                      selectedContacts.add(contact); `   the (contact) gets an error saying 'The argument type 'Contact' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.dartargument_type_not_assignable'

Comment: and for the future I would recommend you to learn about State Managment

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt

Comment: great. thank you! I'm just starting out with flutter and programming so I will take a look at that.

Comment: If answer was helpful I'll appreciate if you accept the answer and rate it up =)

Comment: have aceepted answer. I cant rate it up as im <15 reputation