# Selecting a single CheckboxListTile item selects multiple ones?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

On the code below, selecting "Option A" automatically selects "Option B" aswell.

This code is basically a copy paste from [CheckboxListTile class documentation example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html), twice.

```
class Alergias extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AlergiasState createState() => _AlergiasState();
}

class _AlergiasState extends State<Alergias> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    ...
      body: Column(
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: const Text("Option A"),
            value: timeDilation != 1.0,
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                timeDilation = value ? 2.0 : 1.0;
              });
            },
          ),
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: const Text("Option B"),
            value: timeDilation != 1.0,
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                timeDilation = value ? 2.0 : 1.0;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't understand why this happens or if it has something to do with the StatefulWidget State. Can anyone help me?

Comment: because you use the same value timeDilation != 1.0 . Are you looking for radio?

Comment: could you describe your expected result? thanks.

Comment: @chunhunghan Hello! Sorry, I didn't see your comments. I'm still learning how to get around the website. The expected result was to select only a single item :). I didn't understand what you meant by "are you looking for radio?" though. Thanks for your response!

Comment: sorry for late response but i got simple solution without any packages, look once this might be help in future - 
1. Select only one from list - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71662868/9372923
2. Select multiple from list - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71672197/9372923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is arising due to the Same `timeDilation` variable used in both the `CheckboxListTile`.
Check out the code below,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show timeDilation;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  var value1 = timeDilation.abs();
  var value2 = timeDilation.abs();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children : <Widget>[
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: const Text("Option A"),
            value: value1 != 1.0,
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                value1 = value ? 2.0 : 1.0;
              });
            },
          ),
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: const Text("Option B"),
            value: value2 != 1.0,
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                value2 = value ? 2.0 : 1.0;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are new to Flutter. Welcome to the Flutter community! The reason why both of your `CheckBoxListTile` are selecting at the same time is that because you are using the same value for both of them. You've set the value of the `CheckBoxListTile` to `timeDilation`, changing the value of timeDilation will result to selecting both `CheckBoxListTile` at once.
If you only have to options, I would suggest using a boolean to hold the value:

```
bool _first;
CheckboxListTile(
            title: const Text("Option B"),
            value: _first??false,
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                _first=true;
              });
            },
          ),
CheckboxListTile(
            title: const Text("Option B"),
            value: _first??true?false:true,
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                _first=false;
              });
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Hello! Yes, I am new :). Thank you for your answer! I understand the reason now, but unfortunately I have five options, so I'd have to use a lot of bools. Either way, this was really helpful :).