# how to make checkbox state active

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying for everytime i click on a checkbox the state changes to active , currently when i click on a checkbox all the values get update , my checkbox is dynamic , how can i ensure that when i click on a specific checkbox that specific state gets active ?

```
 bool? isChecked = false;

   return ref.watch(getMealByIdProvider(widget.ID)).when(
          data: (e) => Scaffold(
            body: ListView(
              children: [
                  for (int i = 0;
                            i < e.mealName.length;
                            i++)
                          CheckboxListTile(
                              title: Text(e.mealName[i]),
                              value: isChecked,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                if (value == true) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    isChecked = value ;
                                  });
                                 }
                                }
                              })
```

Comment: you can create separate statefulWidget/(Builder) to separate the context & logic. Or for N items you need to use a List<bool> nItems. or create a list to hold checkedItem. another solution is creating a model class.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67704054/how-to-select-multiple-checkboxes-in-flutter-in-checkboxlisttile

Comment: I also recommend multi_select_flutter package. https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter